# How to increase FPS using console commands?

Tags: rust

On my laptop Rust is not running very well, probably because it is not yet optimized due to early alpha stage.

I found a couple of settings that can be enabled in console that increase the FPS a bit:

```
grass.on false
grass.displacement false
```

Are there other settings that I could use to improve Rust performances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The things you can do (through console commands) are:

```
grass.on true/false              Enables or disables grass; Improves FPS for some
grass.displacement true/false    Enables or disables grass displacements.
terrain.idleinterval 0-100       Sets how often to draw unseen terrain; setting to 0 will disable.
gfx.ssaa true/false              enable/disable screen space anti-aliasing.
gfx.grain true/false             enable/disable radiation grain effect.
gfx.shafts true/false            enable/disable sun shafts.
gfx.damage true/false            enable/disable damage indicators.
```

Besides this if its not optimalisation your looking for but actual hardware performance you could alway fiddle with the ingame settings.

Hope this helped.

[Source](http://playrustwiki.com/wiki/Controls_and_Commands)